# How do I decode a row of data using a date range as my parameter

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax-error, peoplesoft

I am trying to do a decode against an Oracle server and return a fiscal year if date ranges fall in between what is listed below.  I keep getting 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis' and I am sure it is something simple or maybe I am not using correct syntax for the date range but any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
SELECT ISSUE_DT,
MAX(DECODE(ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-12','2012',ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-13','2013',ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-14','2014','NONE'))FISCAL_YEAR
FROM PS_GSU_AWD_INFO_VW
```

UPDATE

This is my current SQL statement that returns two columns, the year with quarter and total amount.  I ultimately need the quarter and fiscal year in two separate places:

```
select CASE 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-11' THEN 'FY12 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-11' THEN 'FY12 Q2'
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-12' THEN 'FY12 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-12' THEN 'FY12 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-12' THEN 'FY13 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-12' THEN 'FY13 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-13' THEN 'FY13 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-13' THEN 'FY13 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-13' THEN 'FY14 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-13' THEN 'FY14 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-14' THEN 'FY14 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-14' THEN 'FY14 Q4' 
ELSE 'NO DATA' END AS FISCAL_QUARTER, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AWARDED FROM PS_GSU_AWD_INFO_VW WHERE ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-11' THEN 'FY12 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-11' THEN 'FY12 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-12' THEN 'FY12 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-12' THEN 'FY12 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-12' THEN 'FY13 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-12' THEN 'FY13 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-13' THEN 'FY13 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-13' THEN 'FY13 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-13' THEN 'FY14 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-13' THEN 'FY14 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-14' THEN 'FY14 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-14' THEN 'FY14 Q4' 
ELSE 'NO DATA'  END ORDER BY FISCAL_QUARTER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a query that works.  Not sure if this is best practices or not but here my is code:

```
SELECT DECODE(FISCAL_QUARTER,'FY12 Q1',2012,'FY12 Q2',2012,'FY12 Q3',2012,
'FY12 Q4',2012,'FY13 Q1',2013,'FY13 Q2',2013,'FY13 Q3',2013,'FY13 Q4',2013,'FY14
Q1',2014,'FY14 Q2',2014,'FY14 Q3',2014,'FY14 Q4',2014,2015)as "FISCAL YEAR",
DECODE(FISCAL_QUARTER,'FY12 Q1','Q1','FY12 Q2','Q2','FY12 Q3','Q3','FY12 Q4'
,'Q4','FY13 Q1','Q1','FY13 Q2','Q2','FY13 Q3','Q3','FY13 Q4','Q4','FY14 Q1','Q1',
'FY14 Q2','Q2','FY14 Q3','Q3','FY14 Q4','Q4',2015)as "FISCAL QUARTER",
DECODE(FISCAL_QUARTER,'FY12 Q1',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY12 Q2',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY12 Q3',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY12 Q4',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY13 Q1',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY13 Q2',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY13 Q3',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY13 Q4',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY14 Q1',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY14 Q2',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY14 Q3',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'FY14 Q4',TO_CHAR(TOTAL_AWARDED),'NONE')as "TOTAL AWARDED"
FROM(
select CASE 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-11' THEN 'FY12 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-11' THEN 'FY12 Q2'
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-12' THEN 'FY12 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-12' THEN 'FY12 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-12' THEN 'FY13 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-12' THEN 'FY13 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-13' THEN 'FY13 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-13' THEN 'FY13 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-13' THEN 'FY14 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-13' THEN 'FY14 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-14' THEN 'FY14 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-14' THEN 'FY14 Q4' 
ELSE 'NO DATA' END AS FISCAL_QUARTER, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_AWARDED FROM PS_GSU_AWD_INFO_VW WHERE ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-11' THEN 'FY12 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-11' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-11' THEN 'FY12 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-12' THEN 'FY12 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-12' THEN 'FY12 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-12' THEN 'FY13 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-12' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-12' THEN 'FY13 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-13' THEN 'FY13 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-13' THEN 'FY13 Q4' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JUL-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-SEP-13' THEN 'FY14 Q1' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-OCT-13' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-DEC-13' THEN 'FY14 Q2' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-JAN-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '31-MAR-14' THEN 'FY14 Q3' 
WHEN ISSUE_DT >= '01-APR-14' AND ISSUE_DT <= '30-JUN-14' THEN 'FY14 Q4' 
ELSE 'NO DATA'  END ORDER BY FISCAL_QUARTER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `DECODE` to test anything other than equality.  You can, however, use the much more robust and much more standard `CASE` function

```
CASE WHEN issue_dt >= date '2011-07-01' AND issue_dt <= date '2012-06-30'
     THEN '2012'
     WHEN issue_dt >= date '2012-07-01' AND issue_dt <= date '2013-06-30'
     THEN '2013'
     WHEN issue_dt >= date '2013-07-01' AND issue_dt <= date '2014-06-30'
     THEN '2014'
     ELSE 'NONE'
 END
```

It probably makes sense, though, to do this via a calculation rather than hard-coding every year's range

```
to_char( issue_dt + interval '6' month, 'yyyy' )
```

Comment: I want to use DECODE because I need to return info from multiple columns in one statement and I have not been able to do that with CASE.  My ideal end result is going to have the fiscal year, the quarter, and award amount.  I am writing the statement to create a web service.  I am querying two columns, issue_dt and award_amount.  I want the end result to return a column listing fiscal year, a column returning the quarter, and a column with the total amount

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but you can try this:

```
SELECT 'FY'||to_char(add_months(t.issue_dt,6), 'YY')||' Q'||DECODE(FLOOR(EXTRACT(month from t.issue_dt)/4), 0, '3', 1, '4', 2, '1', 3, '2', 'E') 
FROM t
```